# Import JSON file to MYSQL using Python

Tags: python, mysql, json, python-3.x

Getting error as below:

> ```
> con.commit()
>   ^ SyntaxError: invalid syntax
> ```

Here is the code segment for JSON file to MYSQL using python

```
try:
cursor.execute("""INSERT INTO vehicle (CarYear,make,model,cylinders,VClass,drive,trany,displ,eng_dscr,trans_dscr,mpgData,evMotor,
youSaveSpend,fuleType,fuleType1,barrelsA08,charge120,charge240,city08,city08U,cityA08,cityA08U,cityCD,cityE,cityUF,co2,coA2,co2TailpipeAGpm,
co2TailpipeGpm,comb08,comb08U,combA08,combA08U,combE,combinedCD,combinedUF,engld,feScore,fuelCost08,fuelCostA08,ghgScore,ghgScoreA,highway08,
highway08U,highwayA08,highwayA08U,highwayCD,highwayE,highwayUF,hlv,hpv,id,lv2,lv4,phevBlended,pv2,pv4,CarRange,rangeCity,rangeCityA,rangeHwy,
rangeHwyA,UCity,UCityA,UHighway,UHighwayA,guzzler,tCharger,sCharger,atvType,fuelType2,rangeA,mfrCode,c240Dscr,charge240b,c240bDscr,createdOn,
modifiedOn,startStop,phevCity,phevHwy,phevComb)
VALUES (%s, %s, %s,%s, %s,  %s,%s, %s,  %s,%s, %s,  %s,%s, %s,  %s,%s, %s,  %s,%s, %s,  %s,%s, %s,  %s,%s, %s,  %s,%s, %s,  %s,
%s, %s, %s,%s, %s,  %s,%s, %s,  %s,%s, %s,  %s,%s, %s,  %s,%s, %s,  %s,%s, %s,  %s,%s, %s,  %s,%s, %s,%s,%s, %s,    %s,%s, %s,
%s,%s, %s,  %s,%s, %s,  %s,%s, %s,  %s,%s, %s,  %s,%s, %s,  %s,%s, %s,  %s,%s),
(CarYear, make, model, cylinders,VClass, drive, trany, displ, eng_dscr, trans_dscr,mpgData,evMotor,youSaveSpend,fuleType,fuleType1,
barrelsA08,charge120,charge240,city08,city08U,cityA08,cityA08U,cityCD,cityE,cityUF,co2,coA2,co2TailpipeAGpm,co2TailpipeGpm,comb08,
comb08U,combA08,combA08U,combE,combinedCD,combinedUF,engld,feScore,fuelCost08,fuelCostA08,ghgScore,ghgScoreA,highway08,highway08U,
highwayA08,highwayA08U,highwayCD,highwayE,highwayUF,hlv,hpv,id,lv2,lv4,phevBlended,pv2,pv4,CarRange,rangeCity,rangeCityA,rangeHwy,
rangeHwyA,UCity,UCityA,UHighway,UHighwayA,guzzler,tCharger,sCharger,atvType,fuelType2,rangeA,mfrCode,c240Dscr,charge240b,c240bDscr,
createdOn,modifiedOn,startStop,phevCity,phevHwy,phevComb))"""
```

``

```
con.commit()

except pymysql.Error as e:
    raise
    sys.exit(1)

finally:
    if con:
        con.close()
```

NEED HELP Please.. just writing here because of policy

Comment: you missed the closing bracket `)` in cursor.execute

Comment: you need to add `)` after closing the string `"""`

Comment: Now its showing this error!! See I edited again

Comment: The use of CAPS in your question and responses here is actually rather irritating. You are _not_ going to get a good response if you keep implying that you're shouting at us. The urgency of your problem is your problem, not ours. Remember, you're asking for help on our time for free.

Comment: In general it is good to test the query in MySQL first before adding it to Python (or other) script.

Comment: @Mika72 Yes I did same but still getting error :(

Comment: while Hardcoding SQL its working fine

Answer (score 0):

you need to split the SQL string: """ INSERT ... """, the values, something like: 
"""INSERT INTO vehicle (CarYear,make,model,cylinders,VClass,drive,trany,displ,eng_dscr,trans_dscr,mpgData,evMotor,
youSaveSpend,fuleType,fuleType1,barrelsA08,charge120,charge240,city08,city08U,cityA08,cityA08U,cityCD,cityE,cityUF,co2,coA2,co2TailpipeAGpm,
co2TailpipeGpm,comb08,comb08U,combA08,combA08U,combE,combinedCD,combinedUF,engld,feScore,fuelCost08,fuelCostA08,ghgScore,ghgScoreA,highway08,
highway08U,highwayA08,highwayA08U,highwayCD,highwayE,highwayUF,hlv,hpv,id,lv2,lv4,phevBlended,pv2,pv4,CarRange,rangeCity,rangeCityA,rangeHwy,
rangeHwyA,UCity,UCityA,UHighway,UHighwayA,guzzler,tCharger,sCharger,atvType,fuelType2,rangeA,mfrCode,c240Dscr,charge240b,c240bDscr,createdOn,
modifiedOn,startStop,phevCity,phevHwy,phevComb)
VALUES (%s, %s, %s,%s, %s,  %s,%s, %s,  %s,%s, %s,  %s,%s, %s,  %s,%s, %s,  %s,%s, %s,  %s,%s, %s,  %s,%s, %s,  %s,%s, %s,  %s,
%s, %s, %s,%s, %s,  %s,%s, %s,  %s,%s, %s,  %s,%s, %s,  %s,%s, %s,  %s,%s, %s,  %s,%s, %s,  %s,%s, %s,%s,%s, %s,    %s,%s, %s,
%s,%s, %s,  %s,%s, %s,  %s,%s, %s,  %s,%s, %s,  %s,%s, %s,  %s,%s, %s,  %s,%s)""",
(CarYear, make, model, cylinders,VClass, drive, trany, displ, eng_dscr, trans_dscr,mpgData,evMotor,youSaveSpend,fuleType,fuleType1,
barrelsA08,charge120,charge240,city08,city08U,cityA08,cityA08U,cityCD,cityE,cityUF,co2,coA2,co2TailpipeAGpm,co2TailpipeGpm,comb08,
comb08U,combA08,combA08U,combE,combinedCD,combinedUF,engld,feScore,fuelCost08,fuelCostA08,ghgScore,ghgScoreA,highway08,highway08U,
highwayA08,highwayA08U,highwayCD,highwayE,highwayUF,hlv,hpv,id,lv2,lv4,phevBlended,pv2,pv4,CarRange,rangeCity,rangeCityA,rangeHwy,
rangeHwyA,UCity,UCityA,UHighway,UHighwayA,guzzler,tCharger,sCharger,atvType,fuelType2,rangeA,mfrCode,c240Dscr,charge240b,c240bDscr,
createdOn,modifiedOn,startStop,phevCity,phevHwy,phevComb)

otherwise the whole thing is just a string

Comment: Getting error   VALUES (%s, %s, %s,%s, %s, %s,%s, %s, %s,%s, %s, %s,%s, %s, %s,%s, %s, %s,%s, %s, %s,%s, %s, %s,%s, %s, %s,%s, %s, %s,
         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: line 127, in <module>
    createdOn,modifiedOn,startStop,phevCity,phevHwy,phevComb))                 ERROR

Comment: AttributeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute 'translate'

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42252749/mysql-insert-statement-in-python