# I have two columns in sql and want to insert list values into them respectively. How do I do that with pyhton?

Tags: python, mysql, sql, python-3.x

I have created two columns in MySQL and I have two list values, how do I insert those values into those two columns with python. (columns-wise insertion)

Under pid_data ;table name ,two columns one is candidatepipe and specbreak. I have two lists for each want to insert into that two

I have list1 = [with some values] list2 = [with some values] want to insert these value in those columns respectively with python

```
cur.execute("CREATE TABLE pid_data 
(candidatePipes VARCHAR(255), specBreak VARCHAR(255))") conn.commit()
```

I have tried with loop. for i in list1:

```
cur.execute("INSERT INTO pid_data (candidatePipes) VALUES (?)", i)
```

[image]

Comment: Where are this "two list values"? in what format? *I have created two columns* Show CREATE TABLE instead of a picture.

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? Where exactly are you stuck?

Comment: I have posted an image ; under pid_data ;table name ,two columns one is candidatepipe and specbreak. I have two lists for each want to insert into that two.

Comment: I have list1 = [with some values] list2 = [with some values] want to insert these value in those columns respectively with python

Comment: cur.execute("CREATE TABLE pid_data (candidatePipes VARCHAR(255), specBreak VARCHAR(255))")
conn.commit()

Comment: I have tried with loop.        for i in list1:
    cur.execute("INSERT INTO pid_data (candidatePipes) VALUES (?)", i)

Comment: please edit your question rather than adding such comments.

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan is it okay now? Could you please help me for this?

Comment: @AnimeshMandal Are your both columns null? Because you are adding value in only 1 column. Please check your DB Structure

Comment: @AmanjotKaur yes my both columns are null. They have nothing in it. I have two list values and that I have to insert into those two columns. That is all I want.

Comment: What I mean by null is have you kept the constraint NULL while creating them? Null does not mean that it has records.

Comment: How these lists values are related? I.e. does the record which contains the most first value from first list in one column must contain some specific value (for example the most first from second list) in the second column? or it doesn't matter?

Comment: @AmanjotKaur cur.execute("CREATE TABLE pid_data (candidatePipes VARCHAR(255), specBreak VARCHAR(255))") this is how I created those columns , I am a freshie in sql have very less idea about this. So it might help you to understand.

Comment: @AmanjotKaur *columns are not null* Why do you think so? In MySQL the column which is not defined as NOT NULL explicitly is nullable.

Comment: @Akina lets just make it simple. I am creating a dataframe with two columns for each I have a list for both , Now how I do with sql .

Comment: @AnimeshMandal Please execute `SHOW CREATE TABLE pid_data` and show the result.

Comment: @Akina check this link https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/data-type-defaults.html If the column can take NULL as a value, the column is defined with an explicit DEFAULT NULL clause.

Comment: @AmanjotKaur okay , now how I insert those two list values in those two columns?

Comment: Have you tried https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42252749/mysql-insert-statement-in-python or  https://www.javatpoint.com/python-mysql-insert-operation  or https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_mysql_insert.asp

Comment: @AmanjotKaur it only showing single column now .

Comment: @AmanjotKaur Do you see the difference between "nullable column" and "column with DEFAULT NULL"?  And look this in practice: [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=5ccf0f3cb7826c656b1a9425358c3022).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## length of the lists are identical.

```
list1 = [some values]
list2 = [some values]
sql = 'INSERT INTO table_name (col1, col2) VALUES (%s, %s)'
```

`for elem in zip(list1, list2):
    cur.execute(sql, elem)
    conn.commit()`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that:

1. The lists sizes are equal
2. The lists values are positionally-related

you must use something like (the syntax may be wrong - I'm not familiar with python)

```
for i in range(len(list1)):
    cur.execute("INSERT INTO pid_data (candidatePipes, specBreak) VALUES (?, ?)", (list1[i], list2[i]) )
```

If lists sizes are not equal then you must use the length of the list which is longer, and replace absent values from another list with empty string or some pre-defined literal value.